# create constant object in Java

Tags: java, constants, final

I wonder, In Java How can we create a constant object (but not-reference nor immutable since immutability is a feature to all objects of a class) ?

*First:*

```
final MyClass c = new MyClass();
```

creates a constant reference to non-constant object hence I can do:

```
c.setData(100);
```

*Second:*

String class is a class that all its instances should be constant (a.k.a immutable object). I need to have a kind that I can create from a constant objects and non-constanct objects.

---

In Other words, How to grant the constant-ness to some objects of a class and remove it from other objects. (without the need to wrap this object inside any wrapper).

Comment: Well since there's no `const` keyword in Java and you've already found out that `final` doesn't do what you want.. Short: There doesn't exist anything in Java correlating to const correctness in C++.

Comment: Because const correctness complicates the language and has its own sets of problems as everyone who has ever worked in C++ with a const correct code base that has to call older MS APIs can tell you. Just one more tradeoff the java guys thought was worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you want something along the lines of the `const` keyword in C++, which makes an instance of an otherwise mutable class immutable. However, no direct equivalent for this exists in Java.

If you control the class, you could define an interface that only exposes the getters and use that interface whenever you need a "const" reference - this would not require any wrapping, but it would be rather cumbersome if you need to do this for a lot of classes.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you could do is to extend the base class and override its setter methods so they throw java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException , that way you can create object from the base class or the immutable subclass...

Answer (score 0):

And what about an Enumeration containing only one element ? I think that comes pretty close to what he needs

Comment: You mean the same answer as @ttt ? No this is not what I mean!